# SimpleMessageListenerContainer onMessage get called one time per second

Tags: java, performance, spring-rabbit

SimpleMessageListenerContainer onMessage get called one time per second! I have a consumer implemented ChannelAwareMessageListener. I defined a ThreadLocal time to remember the last time the onMessage get called. At the beginning of onMessage I print out the interval between two calls. I tested by sending many messages 80/s publish rate. And for each message onMessage took 200ms to process. Interval is around 1s. How can I improve it? Thanks!

```
private ThreadLocal<Long> endTime = new ThreadLocal<Long>() {
    @Override protected Long initialValue() {
        return new Long(0);
    }
};
LOG.info("enter time: "+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()-endTime.get().longValue()));
```

Here are my configurations of listener-container and queue:

```
<rabbit:listener-container id="{{consumer_name}}ListenerContainer"
    connection-factory="{{consumer_name}}RabbitConsumerConnectionFactory"
    prefetch="10"
    concurrency="100"
    auto-startup="true">
    <rabbit:listener queues="{{consumer_name}}RabbitQueue" ref="{{consumer_name}}Consumer"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>
<rabbit:queue id="{{consumer_name}}RabbitQueue"
              name="q_{{host_env}}_{{svc.queue_name}}"
              declared-by="{{consumer_name}}ConsumerRabbitAdmin"
              auto-delete="false"
              durable="true"
              exclusive="false"
        />
```

Comment: What is being done in the listener? How many CPUs? How busy are they? If 100% then there's no way to speed it up (assuming the listener code can't be improved). There's nothing in the container that would limit the messages to 1 per second. Perhaps turning on DEBUG logging will shed some light (but it will likely slow it down some more).

Comment: Thank you Gary. I just figured it out, because I have 100 consumers, and my input rate is not big enough so there is no available messages pushed to each consumer. I tested again by reducing the number of consumer to 20. Publish rate is 70/s, the ack rate is ~70/s, each consumer ack rate is about 3.5/s. And the re-enter interval is about 200ms.